# How can i calculate pct changes between groups of colums efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have a set of columsn like so:

```
q1_cash_total, q2_cash_total, q3_cash_total, 
q1_shop_us, q2_shop_us, q3_shop_us,
```

etc, i have about 40 similarly named column names like this. I wish to calculate the pct changes between each of these groups of 3. e.g. i know individually i can do:

```
df[['q1_cash_total', 'q2_cash_total', 'q3_cash_total']].pct_change().add_suffix('_PCT_CHG')
```

to do this for every 3 i do:

```
q1 =  [col for col in df.columns if 'q1' in col ]
q2 =  [col for col in df.columns if 'q2' in col ]
q3 =  [col for col in df.columns if 'q3' in col ]
q_cols = q1+q2+q3
dflist = []
for col in df[q_cols].columns:
    #col[3:] to just get col name without the q1_/q2_ etc 
    print(col[3:])
    cols = [c for c in df.columns if col[3:] in c]
    pct = df[cols].pct_change().add_suffix('_PCT_CHG')
    dflist.append(pct) 

pcts_df = pd.concat(dflist)
```

I cannot think of a cleaner way to do this. Does anybody have any ideas? How can i also do it such that i do the pct change between q1 and q3 too instead of successively.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dataframe containing only the desires columns, for that, [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) column names starting with `q` immediately follow by one or more digits and an underscore (`^q\d+?_`). Remove the prefix and keep only unique column names using [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html). For each unique column name, filter columns with that specific name and apply the percentage change along the columns axis (`.pct_change(axis='columns')`) to obtain the changes between `q1`, `q2` and `q3`.

To get  the percentage change between `q1` and `q3` you can select those columns by name over the previous created dataframe (`df_q`) and apply the same `pct_change` executed earlier.

**df** used as input

```py
   q1_cash_total  q1_shop_us  q2_cash_total  q2_shop_us  q3_cash_total  q3_shop_us  another_col   numCols  dataCols
0             52          93             15          72             61          21           83        87        75
1             75          88             24           3             22          53            2        88        30
2             38           2             64          60             21          33           76        58        22
3             89          49             91          59             42          92           60        80        15
4             62          62             47          62             51          55           64         3        51
```

```py
df_q = df.filter(regex='^q\d+?_')
unique_cols = pd.unique([c[3:] for c in df_q.columns])

dflist = []
for col in unique_cols:
    q_name = df_q.filter(like=col)
    df_s = q_name.pct_change(axis='columns').add_suffix('_PCT_CHG')
    dflist.append(df_s)
    df_s = df_q[[f'q1_{col}', f'q3_{col}']].pct_change(axis='columns').add_suffix('_Q1-Q3')
    dflist.append(df_s)

pcts_df = pd.concat(dflist, axis=1)
```

Output from **pcts_df**

```py
   q1_cash_total_PCT_CHG  q2_cash_total_PCT_CHG  q3_cash_total_PCT_CHG  ...  q3_shop_us_PCT_CHG  q1_shop_us_Q1-Q3  q3_shop_us_Q1-Q3
0                    NaN              -0.711538               3.066667  ...           -0.708333               NaN         -0.774194
1                    NaN              -0.680000              -0.083333  ...           16.666667               NaN         -0.397727
2                    NaN               0.684211              -0.671875  ...           -0.450000               NaN         15.500000
3                    NaN               0.022472              -0.538462  ...            0.559322               NaN          0.877551
4                    NaN              -0.241935               0.085106  ...           -0.112903               NaN         -0.112903

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```